# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400

Tags: java, json, post

I am trying to post a json data to a URL, I have no idea where my code went wrong, I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400 It would be of great help if anyone could help me outwith this issue.

Using postman I can perform the post operation, but through code it always throws 400.

I tried searching many posts but none of them work, I am stuck with this error.

try {

```
        URL url = new URL("https://XXX/approvals");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("APIKEY", "abc");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer abc");


        String input = "{\"users\":\"100\"}";

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

     }
```

Error:

Post parameters : {"users":"100"}
Response Code : 400

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400Cannot Estabilish Connection Failed : HTTP error code : 400

```
at com.Test.main(Test.java:46)
```

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using?

Comment: This is a bad request error, can you attach the exception.

Comment: oauth, also tried using HttpClient and it throws HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Content-Type: application/json, Connection: keep-alive, Server: Apache, X-Ariba-Debug: C138_UI4, X-Ariba-CorrelationId: ddef8db5, Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept, authorization, x-ariba-authorization, cache-control, x-requested-with, content-length, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true, Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD, AAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: https://developer.ariba.com

Comment: @NiVeR I have added the exception message

Comment: Have you tried specifying the value as an integer rather than string, `"{\"users\":100}"`

Comment: @wrlee Yes I did and it gave me the same error